# Passing of a struct array from called contract to calling contract

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct

I am currently developing a dAPP and I am splitting it in 2 distinct contracts. I will be calling functions from contract A to contract B. In contract B I have an array of struct which I can manipulate. However I need some functions called from A to B and B must return the struct array or a copy of it to contract A. How can I do this? If I use a mapping instead of struct arrays, can I still do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract A {
  B private b;

  constructor (B _b) public {
    b = _b;
  }

  function bar () public {
    B.S [] memory structs = b.foo ();
  }
}

contract B {
  struct S {
    uint x;
    uint y;
  }

  S [] private structs;

  function foo () public view returns (S [] memory) {
    return structs;        
  }
}
```

With mappings situation is a bit more complicated because:

1. ABI encoding does not support mappings
2. Mappings do not store the keys, but only the values

However you may return mapping like this:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract A {
  B private b;

  constructor (B _b) public {
    b = _b;
  }

  function bar () public {
    address [] memory keys;
    B.S [] memory values;

    (keys, values) = b.foo ();
  }
}

contract B {
  struct S {
    uint x;
    uint y;
  }

  mapping (address => S) private structs;
  address [] private keys;

  function foo () public view returns (address [] memory _keys, S [] memory _values) {
    _keys = keys;
    _values = new S [] (_keys.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++)
      _values [i] = structs [_keys [i]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Mikhail, thank you you have saved my day :)

Comment: You are welcome.  BTW, people usually say "thank you" here by accepting the answer.

Comment: Upvoted. I wonder if this deserves warnings about scalability or the practice of using experimental code in production for anyone else who comes across this.